# Ingesting a CSV file thru Polybase without knowing the sequence of columns

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, polybase, azure-synapse

I am trying to ingest a few CSV files from Azure Data Lake into Azure Synapse using Polybase. 
There is a fixed set of columns in each CSV file and the column names are given on the first line. However, the columns can come in different ordering sequence.

In Polybase, I need to declare external table which I need to know the exact sequence of columns during design time and hence I cannot create the external table. Are there other ways to ingest the CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this directly with Polybase because as you noted the CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE statement requires the column declarations. At runtime, the CSV data is then mapped to those column names.

You could accomplish this easily with Azure Data Factory and Data Flow (which uses Polybase under the covers to move the data to Synapse) by allowing the Data Flow to generate the table. This works because the table is generated after the data has been read rather than before as with EXTERNAL.

For the sink Data Set, create it with parameterized table name [and optionally schema]:
[image]

In the Sink activity, specify "Recreate table":
[image]

Pass the desired table name to the sink Data Set from the Pipeline:
[image]

Be aware that all string-based columns will be defined as VARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: Thanks Joel. May I know at which point does this solution actually create the columns? I would be receiving a CSV file with the 1st line showing my column names but ordering is unknown.

Comment: The Sink will create the table with whatever columns it finds - the ordinal position of the columns shouldn't matter.

Comment: if Sink creates the table dynamically, how does it know which column is using which data type?

Comment: It extrapolates from the column types in the Data Flow. If they are all Strings, you can use Derived Column to convert them to the desired type before the Sink. As I noted in my answer, all String columns will end up as VARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: Thank you Joel, i will probably adopt this solution instead of depending on creating EXTERNAL tables